# Centralized shared gulp dependencies for multiple projects?

Tags: dependencies, gulp, node-modules

Is it possible to share gulp dependencies for multiple projects instead of having them in every project folder (as it is for default)?

This is what I'm aiming for (every client project would have the same structure):

```
/shared
node_modules
shared_scss
shared_js
gulpfile.js

/client-project-1
client_scss
client_js
gulpfile.js

/client-project-2
/client-project-3
/client-project-n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing dependencies in Node.js is easy: given a module id that requires a lookup, the [`require.resolve` algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) searches in [`node_modules` directories](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) and walks up the directory tree doing that until module is resolved:

> If the module identifier passed to `require()` is not a native module, and does not begin with `'/'`, `'../'`, or `'./'`, then Node.js starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds `/node_modules`, and attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached.

Back to your question, you can basically put your projects into one directory with a shared `node_modules` subdirectory and every `require` call from any of your client project directories will load the dependency from that shared `node_modules` (if it exists and not overridden in the client directory).

```
shared
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── shared_js
├── shared_scss
├── gulpfile.js
|
├── client-project-1
│   ├── client_js
│   ├── client_scss
│   └── gulpfile.js
|
├── client-project-2
├── client-project-3
└── client-project-n
```

If you also symlink `shared_js` into `shared/node_modules/shared_js`, client projects will be able to require them with `require('shared_js/...')`.

Alternatively, you can install shared dependencies [globally](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) into `$HOME/.node_modules` or `$NODE_PATH`, but this is discouraged.